# Why can I not layer my hats?

Tags: feature-request, hats

It would seem a lot of fun if it were possible to layer hats, some combinations would be hysterical!

It also doesn't seem possible to change the avatar for my profile during this time, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should post this question on Stack Exchange meta. I think though it's already been asked, and dismissed by the devs.

Comment: See [How about multiple hats?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159307/273494)

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_500_Hats_of_Bartholomew_Cubbins).

Comment: @ColleenV  I tried doing the accepted Answer in you comment, i.e. saving the avatar with the hat and then manually layering, but that's the reason for my second question, can not seem to upload the saved image. I'm trying again.

Comment: I'm at work, so I can't test, but I would check to make sure you "flatten" your image before you save it. Somewhere around here there must be a description on the limits for avatars. You might search the help or Meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41277 that is some detail about changing avatars. If you're using Facebook, that might be the difference.

Comment: Not using Facebook, so I tried to change my avatar, set the old one up with a hat I wanted, took a screenshot section of the avatar (so it's "flat"), tried to load it as new picture in "edit settings", and no dice...

Comment: That's really odd - it sounds like some sort of caching maybe. I'm afraid you've reached the limits of my technical support skills :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't layer multiple hats through the UI provided by SE. However that doesn't prevent you from taking a screen shot of your avatar with a hat on, setting that as your new avatar and putting another hat on top of it. It's some work, but if you really really want to, you can.

I did a quick test and I was able to change my avatar, so I'm not sure why you can't.

Comment: So I tried doing your steps and it didn't work, but, when I changed from using my old avatar to using the identicon, the hat which was on my old avatar was now on the identicon, which is unexpected as it should be only the identicon after the change.